# Ionic App w/ Cordova, how to embed camera?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am fairly new to Node.js and have begun making my own app with Ionic & Cardova Camera API..

I currently have it launch the camera of the ***android device*** using this [demo.](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/cordova-camera/)

What I want to do is embed the camera itself into the app rather than launch the camera but am clueless on where to start..

Does Cordova support this type of functionality or will I have to use PhoneGap?

For example this in [phonegap.](https://github.com/performanceactive/phonegap-custom-camera-plugin)

Or perhaps writing a custom camera myself?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can do so with Ionic. Take a look at this [official guide](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/cordova-camera/).

A short rundown is this:

- cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
- use it like this for example:

  ```js
  function takePicture() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageURI) {

      // imageURI is the URL of the image that we can use for
      // an <img> element or backgroundImage.

    }, function(err) {

      // Ruh-roh, something bad happened

    }, cameraOptions);
  }
  ```
- Take a look at the [finished project on GitHub](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-example-cordova-camera)

Comment: I have that working on my project already.. I want to actually put the camera into the app instead of launching it & then going back.